# SVN: How to store public and private code in a repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

We have a lot of projects going on in my company. We have some common code (for very common stuff like file manipulation, data storage, events management....) accessible by everyone (let's call them `public`) and some more project-specific code (not planned to be reused because they are too specific) that should only be accessible to project team members (because they could have some IP that all company members are not allowed to access), let's call them `private`.

I'm having a hard time making this possible with SVN.

Here is what I tried so far:

**1- I tried to create a single repository with:**

- public folder storing `public` code
- private folder with one sub-direcory per project to store project-specific `private` code:

  - private/project1
  - private/project2

On the SVN server, I can easily manage permissions and give everyone access to `public` and only allow the right users to access each project `private` folder.

But the limitation I got is that **users are not allowed to create branches anymore**. Because a branch can only be created if you have read permission on ALL folders of the folder you are creating a branch from.

Note: Having some super-user allowed to create branches would fix the problem....but it's not acceptable because those users would see code they are not supposed to see....

**2- I tried to create one public repository and one private repository per project.**

- `private` repositories may import `public` one as svn:external
- or `public` repository may import `private` ones as svn:external

Both works almost the same.

On the SVN server, I can easily manage permission (at repository level instead of folder level). Then, branches can be created....but:

- It make it hard to know which version of `public` repo should be used with which version of `private` one...and at some point you end up with working copies where `private` code does not compiled anymore because you're not using the good version of `public` one
- It is a pain upon commit because you often have to commit twice (one for `public` changes + one for `private` changes)
- It makes branch management hard to do (with branches in `public` and `private` repos to maintain and synchronize).

Would there be a third alternative?

Or could anyone suggest something to fix the limitations encountered in solution 1- and 2- above?

Answer (score 0):

You could re-arrange where you put trunk, tags, branches, etc. Instead of `/trunk/private/project1` and `/branches/branchname/private/project1`, use `/private/project1/trunk` and `/private/project1/branches/branchname`.

This is the recommended layout in the [svn book chapter on repository layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The link you provide is very interesting because it talks specifically about my problem. But I don't undertsand precisely how would this help...how would the developper create his working copy in the end (will he have to do two checkouts)?

Comment: If the developer needs both projects, yes, he could use multiple working copies. But if the relative paths between the directories matter that can get frustrating. Another option would be to use [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) properties to pull in the common-code projects, for example, in an appropriate directory. This assumes everyone working on the project has read access to its dependencies.

Comment: This ends up with too complex branch management in the end (because private code may use public code, so creating a private branche would require creating a public branch too....).

Comment: Yeah it would, if you need to make changes in both places. That would be one disadvantage. But on many projects one will often only need to change one or the other.

Comment: And we often do that....sorry, I can't accept that answer as it's not acceptable for me ;-)